# posts_per_page increment additional post

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

```
 <?php // the query to set the posts per page to 3
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    =>  3, 
            'paged'             =>  $paged ,
            'order'             =>  'ASC',
        );
     $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args ) ?>    
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
        //Content
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- pagination -->
    <div>
        <?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
            pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages);
        } ?>                          
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Works on pagination that its show 3 post but initially it shows 4 posts on page 1.

Comment: Have you tested this code in a vanilla environment i.e. without plugins and with a default theme? Sounds like something is interfering with the query i.e. using the `pre_get_posts` hook

Comment: I'm on `_s` theme  tried disabling active plugin still same..

Comment: Thanks @TheDeadMedic , the 1th post is a sticky one, which its always stick at first one which i forgot.